# How to compare arrays within an object and, if in a position all the arrays have the value true, return their index

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have to randomise the disponibility array, so I have this which just worked fine.

```js
var members = [{
    name: "Jack",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Paula",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Oscar",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
];




var getRandomDisponibility = (() => {
  var randomBoolean = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < members[i].disponibility.length; x++) {
      var saveboolean = randomBoolean()
      members[i].disponibility[x] = saveboolean;
    }
  }
  return members;
})()

console.log(members)
```

But now I need to compare the four resulting arrays and, if in a position they all return true, get the index of that position. I've tried different ways and loops and can't get anything consistent :(

I've searched the forum but I can't find an answer that really works for me, sorry if it's repeated.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix it into a [mcve]

Comment: I see something wrong there - instead of `for (var i = 0; i < disponibility.length; i++) {  ` you should have `for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {  `. Also your question is not clear, please write example of what is your input and what should be the output.

Answer (score 0):

If the disponibilities' lengths are the same, then it's easy to implement: just swap the order in which the loops are embeddeded in each other:

```js
var members = [{
    name: "Jack",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Paula",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Oscar",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
];

{
  let randomBoolean = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < members[i].disponibility.length; x++) {
      var saveboolean = randomBoolean()
      members[i].disponibility[x] = saveboolean;
    }
  }
}

const findCommonDisponibility = (members, disponibilityLength) => {
  for(let i = 0; i < disponibilityLength; i++){
    if(members.every(({disponibility}) => disponibility[i]))
      return i
  }
  return -1
}

console.log(members)
console.log(findCommonDisponibility(members, members[0].disponibility.length))
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, i will try :)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
    var members = [{
        name: "Jack",
        disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
      },
      {
        name: "Mary",
        disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
      },
      {
        name: "Paula",
        disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
      },
      {
        name: "Oscar",
        disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
      },
    ];




    var getRandomDisponibility = (() => {
      var randomBoolean = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;
      for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < members[i].disponibility.length; x++) {
          var saveboolean = randomBoolean()
          members[i].disponibility[x] = saveboolean;
        }
      }
      return members;
    })()
console.log(getRandomDisponibility);
//compare

var output = new Array(8).fill(true);
for (var j = 0 ; j<8 ;j++){
    for (var i = 0 ; i<getRandomDisponibility.length;  i++){
   
        output[j] = output[j] && getRandomDisponibility[i].disponibility[j];
    }
if( output[j]) console.log('are all true on [' + j +']!!')

}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution where you can keep track of all matching disponibilities.

```js
var members = [{
    name: "Jack",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Mary",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Paula",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
  {
    name: "Oscar",
    disponibility: new Array(8).fill(true)
  },
];

// this is a shorter way to create random disponibility
function randomDisponibility(length) {
    return new Array(length).fill().map(_ => Math.random() > .5);
}


var getRandomDisponibility = (() => {
  var randomBoolean = () => Math.random() >= 0.5;
  for (var i = 0; i < members.length; i++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < members[i].disponibility.length; x++) {
      var saveboolean = randomBoolean()
      members[i].disponibility[x] = saveboolean;
    }
  }
  return members;
})()


function matchingDisponibilities(members) {
    // create an array like [0, 1, 2, 3, …]
    const match = new Array(members[0].disponibility.length).fill().map((_,i) => i);
  
  // filter this array and only keep indexes when all disponibilities are true. If there is no matching disponibility returns an empty array
  return match.filter(i => members.every(member => member.disponibility[i]));

}

console.log(members, matchingDisponibilities(members))
```